# How to determine how many visible images within spans with the same "data-id" attribute have the same 'longdesc' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make it so that when someone enables more than one secondary phone, they are alerted that there may be charges. They are allowed to have one primary, and one secondary.

They are able to set the phones active themselves, and they should be alerted when they try to activate more than one secondary phone. They should also be told to call customer service if they try to disable their primary phone. (That part is working.)

From the code provided, you can see what parts are working. I am hard-coding some of the values here for an example. In the sample code, I am searching for how many times the 'longdesc' of 1234 appears in visible images.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Or, if there is a better way to search for how many times the value 1234 appears in visible images in 'secondary' spans?

```js
 
  $(".tog").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var option = $(this).attr('name');
  if (option == "primary") {
   alert("Please call customer service to set the Primary phone on the account.");
  }
  else {
   $('img',this).toggle();
   if (search($(this).find('img').attr('longdesc')) > 1)
    document.getElementById('alert').value = "More than 1 selected.";
   else
    document.getElementById('alert').value = "1 or less selected.";
  }
 });

function search(v) {
 var numfound = 0;
 var out = document.querySelectorAll('img[longdesc]' == v);
 [].forEach.call(out, function(x) {
  numfound++;
 });
 return numfound;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Primary Phone
<span name="primary" data-id="784" class="tog">
<img longdesc="1234" alt="on" align="top" style="width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
Second Phone
<span name="secondary" data-id="784" class="tog">
<img longdesc="1234" alt="on" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
Third Phone
<span name="secondary" data-id="784" class="tog">
<img longdesc="1234" alt="on" align="top" style="width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
<span id='alert'></span>
```

Comment: Id should be unique.

Comment: You are not using the `id` attribute correctly. The `id` value must always be unique within a page - that's the point of `id`. If you would like another way to identify and group elements, use CSS classes or the `data-*` attribute. You are also using the `name` attribute incorrectly as this is only valid on form elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc.), not `span`.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I was not aware of the data-* attribute. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is searching for this, I discovered jquery's multiple selectors and other things that helped. First, thank you to Edison and Scott for their help.

What I ended up using that worked best was several "data-" elements and a complex selector statement in jquery. We also decided not to allow multiple secondary phones altogether, which made the answer a bit different, but this all works perfectly now.

Here is the new snippet:

```js
 $(".tog").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-phone-id');
  var option = $(this).attr('data-name');
  var contactId = $(this).attr('data-contactId');
  var el = this;
  var found = $("span[data-name='"+option+"'][data-contactId='"+contactId+"'][data-phone-id!="+id+"]");
  found.each(function(){
   var thisspan = this;
   var image = $("img[alt='on']:visible",this);
   image.each(function() {
    $('img',thisspan).toggle();
   });
  });
  if (option == "primary") {
   alert("Please call customer service to set the Primary phone on the account.");
  }
  else {
    $('img',el).toggle();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Primary Phone
<span data-phone-id="121" data-name="primary" data-contactId="784" class="tog">
<img longdesc="1234" alt="on" align="top" style="width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
Second Phone
<span data-phone-id="122" data-name="secondary" data-contactId="784" class="tog">
<img longdesc="1234" alt="on" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
Third Phone
<span data-phone-id="123" data-name="secondary" data-contactId="784" class="tog">
<img alt="on" align="top" style="width:22px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" />
<img alt="off" align="top" style="display:none;width:22px" src="https://www.sfpcu.org/UserControls/BrowserDetection/images/red-x-mark.png" /></span>
<span id='alert'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID cannot be repeated. If at you apply any logic on that, only first occurrence of the ID is considered. Try using class instead.

**HTML:**

```
<span>
 <img src="" class="class1" longdesc="123" /> 
 <img src="" class="class2" longdesc="123" /> 
 <img src="" class="class1" /> 
 <img src="" class="class1" /> 
 <img src="" class="class1" longdesc="123" /> 
</span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var count = 0;

$(".class1").each(function( el) {
  if($(this).attr('longdesc'))
    count++;
});
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am already using class for toggling the images.

Comment: No problem. You can dynamically create one more class similarly with different class name.

Comment: You *can* write any markup you want, so yes, `id` *can* be repeated. But, the HTML will not be valid at that point, so realistically, "no", `id` can't be repeated.

Comment: you are right scott. It was a typo. i wrote "can" instead of "can't". My bad.

Comment: Thank you Edison. Adding a second class might help. I still need to figure out how to count only the number of images that are "VISIBLE" ie. where display is NOT set to 'None'.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add one more condition inside if statement.
if($(this).attr('longdesc') && ($(this).css('display') != 'none'))
    count++;

Comment: Edison, what if I don't know what the class is in the javascript (in other words, I am adding it dynamically elsewhere) so I need to just loop through every image that resides inside any span with the same dynamic class?

Comment: Alternate option if you do not want to use class is this. 
<span id="imgRoot">...</span>

$("#imgRoot > img").each(..);